# How can I use reflection to pass each list of "MyTypes" to a generic method with a constraint of T:MyType?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

How can I use reflection to pass each list of "MyTypes" to a generic method with a constraint of T:MyDataObject?

```
public interface IAllMyTypes
{
    List<FirstType> MyType1 { get; set; }
    List<SecondType> MyType2 { get; set; }
    List<ThirdType> MyType3 { get; set; }
}
```

FirstType, SecondType, and ThirdType inherit from MyDataObject (as demonstrated below), but have different properties.

```
public class FirstType : MyDataObject
{
  //various properties
}
```

I've been unable to pass the data into a method with this signature:

```
void DoSomething<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) where T : MyDataObject;
```

The error is that "type arguments can not be inferred."

Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
public void DoSomethingWithAllMyTypes(IAllMyTypes allMyTypes)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in allMyTypes.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var x = propertyInfo.GetValue(allMyTypes) as IList;//im not sure what to do here
        if(x==null) throw new Exception("still wrong");

        DoSomething(x);
    }
}
```

All of the code in DoSomething(..) works correctly if I provide the properties directly which looks like:

```
public void DoSomethingWithAllMyTypes(IAllMyTypes allMyTypes)
{
    DoSomething(allMyTypes.MyType1);
    DoSomething(allMyTypes.MyType2);
    DoSomething(allMyTypes.MyType3);
}
```

Comment: `IList` (non-generic) would work fine.

Comment: If the only reason you're doing these steps is to call DoSomething multiple times, consider a data structure like List<Type> typelist = new List<Type> { typeof(A), typeof(B), typeof(C) }; rather than your your IAllMyTypes.  Then you could iterate over that, and change the function signature of DoSomething.

Comment: Should it be `allMyTypes.GetType().GetProperties()` or do you want `typeof(IAllMyTypes).GetProperties()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use reflection, you can invoke your helper method using reflection, too:

You will have to obtain a `MethodInfo` to a *generic* method and create a generic method reflection handle to actually `Invoke` the method. The type `T` of the generic method needs to be obtained at runtime in that case.

```
public void DoSomethingWithAllMyTypes(IAllMyTypes allMyTypes)
{
    var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("DoSomething", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in allMyTypes.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var x = propertyInfo.GetValue(allMyTypes, null);
        if(x==null) throw new Exception("still wrong");

        // obtain the type from the property - other techniques can be used here.
        var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] {propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]})
        //execute the generic helper
        genericMethod.Invoke(this, new[]{x});
    }
} 

public void DoSomething<T>(IList<T> list) where T : MyDataObject {

}
```

Comment: Dropped this in and worked first shot! This is exactly it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Not sure if this needs a whole new question, but I'm doing something similar elsewhere with a method DoSomethingElse(IEnumerable<MyDataObject> list) and I am attempting to pass to the same DoSomething method from earlier, however, I am getting an error: Object of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyDataObject]' 
cannot be converted to type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FirstType]'. I tried to modify the above example to do it, but clearly I have something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to find a case where you'd need to structure your data the way you did without over-complicating things. If you've found a legit case please comment and I'll update my answer to reflect your needs.

You can start with your base class, make it abstract and put an abstract method in it `DoSomething`

```
public abstract class MyDataObject{
  public string SomeSharedProperty{get;set;}
  protected abstract DoSomething(); 
}

public class FirstType: MyDataObject{ 
  protected override DoSomething(){
    Console.WriteLine(SomeSharedProperty);
  }
}


public class Consumer{
  public void DoSomethingWithAllMyTypes(List<MyDataObject> source)
  {
    source.ForEach(x=>x.DoSomething());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Linq method call `Cast<T>` to convert your list to the right type

```
public void DoSomethingWithAllMyTypes(IAllMyTypes allMyTypes)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in allMyTypes.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var x = propertyInfo.GetValue(allMyTypes) as IEnumerable
        if(x==null) throw new Exception("still wrong");

        DoSomething(x.Cast<MyDataObject>());
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work because the type of T in DoSomething is "MyDataObject" instead of whatever the real type is such as FirstType, SecondType, etc which causes the reflection in that code to only have access to the members of MyDataObject.

Comment: @user2565663 No that is not true, reflection wouldn't care, because GetType would return the true type.

Comment: I've run this example and that is not what is happening. Can you share some code that shows what you're saying is true? When I am inside of DoSomething T is a MyDataObject and I don't know how you would be able to GetType on that and get a different type.

Comment: @user2565663 inside `DoSomething<T>(T value)`: `typeof(T)` will return MyDataObject however `value.GetType()` will return the true type of value regardless of how you've cast it.  For example try having an object in variable `x` that is of type `FirstType` and then call `DoSomething((MyDataObject)x)`

Comment: Ohhh, ok, I see what you are saying now. I thought you meant to GetType on T. Yes, you are correct that the actual object itself would still know its true type. I wrote the rest of the code to operate on the T being the correct true type so I'm not sure this would easily fit into my code, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @user2565663 If you are using reflection then you really shouldn't be using generics, generics are really for non reflection based approaches where you need to return the original type or at compile time need the absolute type. Your code would function just as well if you made DoSomething non generic accepting an object of type `MyDataObject` and using GetType on the value (after checking its not null!)

Comment: Wow, thanks Bob, you've really got me thinking. I was trying to figure out why T would exist if I'm not getting the type from it, and with the help of your follow up reply I think I now understand. It sounds like I was using generics wrong all along. Thank you for taking the time to clarify in your follow ups.